# How to separate paragraphs in a string?

Tags: c#, regex, string, escaping, string-literals

I was trying to take a multi-line string which was concluded of a few paragraphs and split it into a few individual texts.

I realized that whenever I skip a line there is a sequence of \n\r in there. Afterwards I thought that each new line starts with a \n and end with a \r. Therefor, I wrote the following code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication15
{
   class Program
   {
    struct ParagraphInfo
    {
        public ParagraphInfo(string text)
        {
            int i;
            Text = text;
            i = text.IndexOf('.');
            FirstSentence = text.Substring(0, i);
        }

        public string Text, FirstSentence;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int tmp = 0;
        int tmp1 = 0;
        string MultiParagraphString = @"AA.aa.

BB.bb.

CC.cc.

DD.dd.

EE.ee.";

        List<ParagraphInfo> Paragraphs = new List<ParagraphInfo>();

        Regex NewParagraphFinder = new Regex(@"[\n][\r]");
        MatchCollection NewParagraphMatches = NewParagraphFinder.Matches(MultiParagraphString);


        for (int i = 0; i < NewParagraphMatches.Count; i++)
        {
            if (i == 0)
            {
                Paragraphs.Add(new ParagraphInfo((MultiParagraphString.Substring(0, NewParagraphMatches[0].Index))));
            }
            else if (i == (NewParagraphMatches.Count - 1))
            {
                tmp = NewParagraphMatches[i].Index + 3;
                tmp1 = MultiParagraphString.Length - NewParagraphMatches[i].Index - 3;
                Paragraphs.Add(new ParagraphInfo(MultiParagraphString.Substring(tmp, tmp1)));
            }
            else
            {
                tmp = NewParagraphMatches[i].Index + 3;
                tmp1 = NewParagraphMatches[i + 1].Index - NewParagraphMatches[i].Index+3;
                Paragraphs.Add(new ParagraphInfo(MultiParagraphString.Substring(tmp, tmp1)));
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine(MultiParagraphString);
        foreach (ParagraphInfo Paragraph in Paragraphs)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Paragraph.Text);

        }


    }
}
}
```

when I printed each member of Paragraphs one after another alongside the entire text something rather bizarre came appeared. The output of the Paragraph list was this:

AA.aa.

---

CC.cc.

DD.

---

DD.dd.

EE.

---

EE.ee.

---

I can not understand why does this keep happening, and moreover I can not figure out why is the output so different each time.

Sorry if it's a mess but I really need some help here. If anyone has a better idea to do it feel free to share.

Comment: FYI, on Windows the line terminator is \r\n, not \n\r.

Comment: Plus, both are at the _end_ of the line, neither at the _beginning_. .NET has the platform independent `Environment.NewLine` for working with line-feed/carriage return sequences across platforms, that's what you should be doing a replace with, and, regex,.. just, why?

Comment: It sounds like you are wrong in assuming that lines start with an \n and end with an \r - isn't \r\n just CRLF meaning that lines should just end with \r\n - that's how you can split it `var paragraphs = someString.Split(Environment.NewLine)`?

Answer (score 3):

You may try the following:

```
MultiParagraphString.Split(new [] {Environment.NewLine}, 
           StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

That will return a `IEnumerable<String>`. If you want to transform them to your structures just use `Select`:

```
MultiParagraphString.Split(new [] {Environment.NewLine}, 
           StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
          .Select(s => new ParagraphInfo(s)).ToList();
```

Comment: Can you explain the new [] {Environment.NewLine part? I didn't get it, what were you suppose to pass to the method? I generally didn't really understood this function and MSDN failed to be of any particular use this time..

Comment: `Environment.NewLine` returns end of line for particular system (http://bit.ly/1267zb7). `String.Split()` does not accept single string as delimiter -- only array (http://bit.ly/1267KD5) that's where `new []{}` comes from.

Answer (score 0):

> I thought that each new line starts with a \n and end with a \r

No.  `\r\n` is the two-character sequence used to indicate a new line in Windows (and other non-Unix) systems.  It does not signal the "start" and "end" of a paragraph.

To separate into paragraphs, you can use [`string.Split()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf.aspx):

```
string[] paragraphs = MultiParagraphString.Split(new string[]{"\r\n"},
                           StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Comment: [Environment.NewLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline.aspx)

Comment: @GrantThomas I was being explicit to illustrate the purpose of `\r\n`

Answer (score 0):

```
 string text = richTextBox1.Text;
```

**You can ignore paragraphs by using this:**

```
text = text.Replace((char)10, ' ');
```

**You can detect paragraps by using this:**

```
string[] words = s.split('');
foreach (string word in words)
{
if (word.Contains((char)10))
{
MessageBox.Show("A paragraph is here (with brillant English accent)");
}
```

Notes: This codes works only when paragraphs are seperated by enter key on text.