# How to count the number of paragraphs in a string in C#

Tags: c#, regex, paragraph, paragraphs

I'm trying to count the number of paragraphs in a string in C#.

I'm defining a paragraph as a block of text whose parts may be separated by a new line. Paragraphs must be separated by two or more new line. So:

```
This is a paragraph.

This
is
a
paragraph.



This is a paragraph.
```

My first thought was to separate the string through `\n\n` and then count the parts, but this doesn't work properly when there is more than one line-space separating paragraphs, at the beginning and end of files, or if the file only has one line.

How can I accurately get the number of paragraphs in a string, either through a regular expression or through another method?

Comment: Regular expressions can be way to do it, like `/[\r\n][\r\n]+/`

Comment: @Lashane That lets `\r\n` end a paragraph.

Comment: How do you define the end of a paragraph?  Is it any series of more than one `CRLF` pair?  Must there be a `.` followed by an empty line or end-of-file?  Is a line empty if it contains only spaces?  Each option is a different regex :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your definition of paragraph can be easily translated to a regex, to get you all the paragraphs:

```
Regex.Matches(s, "[^\r\n]+((\r|\n|\r\n)[^\r\n]+)*")
```

`[^\r\n]+` means a non-zero number of non-newline characters. `\r|\n|\r\n` are the various forms of newline. And basically, for a paragraph, you need these to alternate.

I think this is a better approach than looking for the paragraph separators, because looking for paragraph separators requires too many special cases to give correct results.

To treat blank lines as empty lines, you can change the definition of "line" from "non-zero number of non-newline characters" to "any number of non-newline characters, followed by a non-blank character, followed by any number of non-newline characters". For simplicity, the only character I've counted as blank that cannot be part of a line break is the space character, but you may want to include other characters (e.g. tab) too.

```
Regex.Matches(s, "[^\r\n]*[^ \r\n]+[^\r\n]*((\r|\n|\r\n)[^\r\n]*[^ \r\n]+[^\r\n]*)*")
```

Also, this is already over the edge of what I think is sufficiently easy to read, so this could use some restructuring, but I'm not sure of the best way to do that.

Comment: @user3651656 `Regex.Matches(ttes, "[^\r\n]+((\r|\n|\r\n)[^\r\n]+)*").Count` should give the count

Comment: Thanks. Just out of curiosity, is there any way to make it treat lines that contain only whitespace characters the same as empty lines?

Comment: @user3651656 It should be possible, but if this is already hard to read, it'll become a lot worse. Will edit when I get the chance to test again.

Answer (score 2):

If you're happy to avoid regex then this works:

```
var paragraphs =
    text
        .Split(
            new [] { Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine },
            StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        .Count();
```

Comment: That's clever! You're right, when you only want to count how many paragraphs there are, it doesn't matter that you sometimes include a bogus newline character in the paragraph.

Comment: @hvd - And, quite frankly, I find regex just makes things hard to understand. Sure regex is efficient for the computer, but it just sucks for humans.

Comment: Actually, your answer does miss one case: it doesn't handle a trailing odd number of newlines: it returns two for `"a" + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine`.

Comment: Yes, I agree that regexes are hard to read, but my primary focus was on correctness, and only after that on readability. In other words, I opted for the most readable way I could think of to get a correct answer. I didn't consider your approach, I hadn't thought of it, but I might have posted it as an answer too if I had.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's the way my string is formatted (it's copied from the contents of a RichEditBox in WinRT), but for me this seems to be returning 1 no matter what is inside the string. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: @user3651656 This answer assumes that all newlines are `Environment.NewLine` (`"\r\n"` on Windows). It's possible that the control you're using uses `"\n"` instead.

Answer (score -2):

You may try the following:

```
MultiParagraphString.Split(new [] {Environment.NewLine}, 
           StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

That will return a IEnumerable. If you want to transform them to your structures just use Select:

```
MultiParagraphString.Split(new [] {Environment.NewLine}, 
           StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
          .Select(s => new ParagraphInfo(s)).ToList();
```

Coppied from question [How to separate paragraphs in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14564846/how-to-separate-paragraphs-in-a-string)

Comment: Did you test it? That returns 6.

Comment: That returns every line, not every paragraph.

Comment: I think this solution may need some modification.

Comment: What kind of modifications? Then this is not an answer to the question which is asked.