# Flexible paragraph counting

Tags: c#, regex

I've looked through [this question,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23987032/how-to-count-the-number-of-paragraphs-in-a-string-in-c-sharp) and I've tried modifying the answer, but I'm still stumped.

I need to count the paragraphs in a string.  However, the paragraphs can be separated by any number of newline characters (1-n newlines), start with or without tabs (0-n tabs), and empty lines that contain only empty characters shouldn't be counted (this is the part that's tripping me up).

Example document:

```
First paragraph.
Second paragraph.
<tab>The third.
<tab> <tab> <tab>
<tab>The fourth.

The fifth.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So, you are looking for at least 1 blank line between paragraphs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split on tab and newline, and remove empty lines

```
text.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine, "\t", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Where(x => x.Trim() != "")
```

see demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Y79QjG

Comment: That works beautifully!  It even handled the entire text of War and Peace very quickly.

Comment: @Griven: have you check all the lines?

Answer (score 1):

With the Split method and this pattern:

```
string[] result = Regex.Split(input, @"(?<=\.)[^\S\n]*\n\s*");
```

[online demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3C%3D%5C.)%5B%5E%5CS%5Cn%5D*%5Cn%5Cs*&i=First%20paragraph.%0D%0ASecond%20paragraph.%0D%0AThe%20third.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20The%20fourth.%0D%0A%0D%0AThe%20fifth.)

**pattern details:**

```
(?<=\.)     # lookbehind: preceded by a literal dot (you can add ! and ? too)
[^\S\n]*    # all whitespace characters except the linefeed (zero or more)
\n          # linefeed character
\s*         # all whitespace characters (zero or more)
```

The number of paragraphs is the number of items in `result[]` once you have removed the last item if it is empty. However, you can avoid the problem of the empty item using:

```
string[] result = Regex.Split(input, @"(?<=\.)[^\S\n]*\n(?>\s*)(?!\z)");
```

[online demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3C%3D%5C.)%5B%5E%5CS%5Cn%5D*%5Cn(%3F%3E%5Cs*)(%3F!%5Cz)&i=First%20paragraph.%0D%0ASecond%20paragraph.%0D%0AThe%20third.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20The%20fourth.%0D%0A%0D%0AThe%20fifth.%0D%0A%0D%0A)

or

```
string[] result = Regex.Split(input, @"(?<=\.)(?!\s*\z)[^\S\n]*\n\s*");
```

[online demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3c%3d%5c.)(%3f!%5cs*%5cz)%5b%5e%5cS%5cn%5d*%5cn%5cs*&i=First+paragraph.%0d%0aSecond+paragraph.%0d%0aThe+third.%0d%0a++++++%0d%0a+++The+fourth.%0d%0a%0d%0aThe+fifth.%0d%0a%0d%0a)

*(Note that if you want to extract each paragraph, you need to trim whitespaces on the right of the last item)*

Comment: That gets me pretty close.  \r\n\t throws the count off, however.  http://imgur.com/a/l8Zgh

Comment: @Griven: Since "Thirteen" doesn't end with a dot or a question/exclamation mark, it is not considered as a paragraph. And you can't remove the `(?<=\.)` condition because, in this case, paragraphs that use several lines will be splitted on the middle.

Comment: Splitting on newline and tabs defines a paragraph, who'da thunk it.

Comment: @sln: yes, strange definition of a paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

For some strange reason this seems to work.
This requires a blank line between paragraphs.
It makes no sense to do it otherwise.

Just do a match, while match, match next thing. Increment a counter.

```
 # @"(?m-)(?:\A|(?>^[^\S\r\n]*\r?\n){1,}(?!\z))"

 (?xm-)
 (?:
      \A 
   |  (?> ^ [^\S\r\n]* \r? \n ){1,}
      (?! \z )
 )
```